# When $(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) : \mathbb{Q}) = 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

maybe this is a stupid question . Anyway, when $(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) : \mathbb{Q}) = 2$, i.e., $\phi(n) = 2$ (where $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\phi(n)$ in terms of $n$'s prime factorization?

Comment: @anon I just know that $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$ if they are coprime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** if $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, then
$$\varphi(n)=(p_1-1)p_1^{a_1-1}\cdots(p_k-1)p_k^{a_k-1}$$
(this formula is an easy restatement of [the one listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Computing_Euler.27s_function)). 
Thus, if $\varphi(n)=2$, could $n$ be divisible by $5$, for instance? What can you deduce about the possible powers of $2$ or $3$ going into $n$?