# Can a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients have a root of unity of order 5 or greater than 6 as a zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

We can find such polynomials with roots of unity of order $1,2,3,4,6$ as a zero as follows:

$x^2-2x+1,x^2+2x+1,x^2+x+1,x^2+1,x^2-x+1$

I suspect these are all the orders I can possibly get, but have no way of proving it.

Any hint or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, those are all. To get a polynomial with integer coefficient that has the $n$th root of unity as a zero, that polynomial must be a multiple of the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$. The degree of that cyclotomic polynomial is given by the Euler totien function $\phi(n)$. And it is known that the listed values of $n$ are the only ones with $\phi(n)\le2$.

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426504/11619),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2043607/11619), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2606016/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am sorry but I want to ask you one more thing. In that sense, this result can be generalized to polynomials of degree k( provided we can determine the totient function with values less than $k+1$), is that correct?

Comment: Yes StAKmod, that generslization is correct.

Comment: One more thing you _can_  do with quadratic equations is get the **real parts** of $n$th roots of unity if the totient function of $n$ is at most 4.  Thus $4x^2+2x-1=0, 2x^2-1=0, 4x^2-2x-1=0, 4x^2-3=0$ give the real parts of primitive fifth, eighth, tenth and twelfth roots of unity respectively.  For getting real parts the limit on the totient function of $n$ is twice the polynomial degree.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thank you, that is very interesting!